# PrestaShop: 500 timeout error on control panel url

Tags: prestashop

My ecommerce website'scontrol panel url has suddenly stopped functioning. I am able to access the url only intermittently (https://www.example.com/custom-admin-url/), and when I do see the login page and after entering the credentials, I get a 500 timeout error after a very longish wait.

I tried changing the PHP parameters, max_execution_time and max_input_time, to 14400 (seconds). Still, the problem persists.

The main website is working just fine. I am unable to find anything worthwhile to fix this. Any pointers in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: A "500 Internal Server" error is a very generic error.  It is your web servers way of saying "something went wrong" or "something unexpected happened".  There is no way of helping you or telling you what it is from just the information you posted.  There is almost always additional information in your log files about the error.  You need to find your log files and look for specific error message in them.